# What does "ever" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I read this sentence:

> Did that ever hit home!

None of [these definitions](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ever?region=us&q=ever) hits home. It's neither a question (in which it would perfectly match) nor a negative sentence. And it does not mean "at any time", and it's not constantly, because it refers to a single event in the past when something shocked him.

Comment: "**4** used for emphasis in questions and other remarks, expressing astonishment or outrage".

Comment: So in other words, it means "That hit home A LOT!"

Comment: @RegDwightΒВBẞ8 Darn. I skipped that part behind "question". Can I downvote my question myself? ;p

Comment: Note that if this were spoken, the emphasis would be placed on the word "that".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an emphasis phrase, in this case. It is meant to say that it did hit home, decisively and definitely, right in the middle of the goal/basket/nose or whatever.

It is, I think, a slight Americanism, although the precise origin I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I have it as rhetorical, ironic: hit home, deep impact, if you have to ask the literal question, it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, it means exactly the same as Wow (! /,) or Boy (here they also would be pragmatic markers subclass emphasis), but probably because of the isoformal adverb, it takes medial (before the infinitive) position in the sentence.

Comment: I can't find an appropriate definition of *isoformal* - will you please elaborate?

Comment: Yes, the mathematicians and geneticists have hijacked the word. In 'He runs fast.' and 'His car is fast.', 'fast' occurs as _intercategorial polysemes_(this term certainly has pedigree), an adverb and an adjective respectively. These usages are probably best not classed as homographs, as they belong in the same family, but neither are they just different senses. I've just used 'isomorphic' to mean 'having identical forms' (spelling and pronunciation); I expect this broader and more basic sense is licensed by OED. [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/formal) has ...

Comment: << formal adj. 1.a. Relating to or involving outward form or structure, often in contrast to content or meaning. >> The prefix _iso_ means 'identical' etc.